# Welches Verb passt zum Wort »Chemotherapie«?

Tags: grammar, verb, verb-usage

> Morgen habe ich Chemotherapie.
>
> Morgen nehme ich an einer Chemotherapie teil.

I have chemotherapy tomorrow.

Ich bin unsicher mit dem Verb »haben«. Wahrscheinlich kann man es umgangssprachlich verwenden. Kann man auch »an etw. teilnehmen« in diesem Zusammenhang benutzen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do not use *teilnehmen* in this case. It would mean a scheduled group event you participate in. So, in a similar context, you would attend a self-help or support group or an AA meeting.

But if you are scheduled for an individual treatment, it is

> (eine Behandlung) haben,

from chemotherapy to dialysis. If you want to be a bit more formal you could use *Termin*, e.g.

> einen Termin für die Chemotherapie haben

Comment: »Erst seit drei Tagen als Medizinstudent im Krankenhaus, und morgen nehme ich schon an einer Chemotherapie teil« ;)

Comment: Mal ganz theoretisch... Was wäre an _therapieren_ für _Therapie_ falsch? Wenn auch sehr unüblich wirst du _therapiert_.

Comment: @Clijsters "Morgen werde ich mit einer Chemotherapie therapiert", hört sich ein bisschen so an, als ob der Sprecher eher eine Gehirnoperation braucht...

Comment: @tofro Natürlich. Keiner zwingt damit zum Pleonasmus; ich dachte an `ich werde chemotherapiert`. Dass es *gut klingt*, wollte ich nicht behaupten, trotzdem danke für den Schmunzler :)

Answer (score 4):

"Haben" wäre hier sehr umgangssprachlich.

Das richtige Verb ist meiner Ansicht nach "sich unterziehen" (das ist dafür ziemlich "gehoben")

> Ab morgen muss ich mich einer Chemotherapie *unterziehen*.

Answer (score 3):

Bei Terminen wie Arztbesuchen, Schule oder Sportverein kann man "haben", "müssen" und "gehen" verwenden.

> Morgen gehe ich zur Chemotherapie.
>
> Morgen habe ich Chemotherapie.
>
> Morgen muss ich zur Chemotherapie.

Im Fall von Behandlungen wie Chemotherapie geht auch

> Morgen werde ich mit (einer) Chemotherapie behandelt.

"Teilnehmen" würde ich hier nicht verwenden, das klingt meiner Meinung nach zu schwach für eine Chemotherapie (mitten drin statt nur dabei).

Comment: "Therapie" bedeutet schon "Behandlung", wenn mich nicht alles täuscht.

Answer (score 3):

I would preferably use

> Morgen bekomme ich eine Chemotherapie.

*Haben* would be OK as well, in analogy to 'einen Termin haben'.

*Teilnehmen* does not fit, this sounds as if you are talking about an event or festivity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is applicable to a person, but in case of a tumor you could also use *chemotherapiert*.

> Keimzelltumoren werden zunächst **chemotherapiert** und eventuell anschließend operiert.
>
> Quote: [Klinikum Esselingen](http://www.klinikum-esslingen.de/home/klinik-fuer-gefaess-und-thoraxchirurgie/schwerpunkte-thoraxchirurgie/mittelfellraumes/?type=98)